# Angular ng-show is not working as expected on table columns

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core-2.0

I am Developing a MVC Application , in which I am creating a table and setting ng-show directives on columns to show hide them . Below is my code

```
   <div class="row" id="angular_filetrs">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-6">
                <wrapper style="margin-left:15%">
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_deleted" ng-model="Category">Hide Category
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_completed" ng-model="SubCategory">Hide Sub Category
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_extra" ng-model="Item">Hide Item
                    </label>
                    <label class="checkbox-inline">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chk_extra" ng-model="SubItem">Hide Sub Item
                    </label>
                </wrapper>
            </div>
        </div>

        <table id="tbl" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th ng-show="!Category">Category Name</th>
                    <th ng-show="!SubCategory">Sub Category Name</th>
                    <th ng-show="!Item">Item Name</th>
                    <th ng-show="!SubItem">Sub Item Name</th>
                    <th>Question Type</th>
                    <th>Question Name</th>
                    <th>Is Active</th>
                    <th>Operation</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @{
                    int counter = 1;
                    foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>@row["Question_Id"]</td>
                            <td ng-show="!Category">@row["CategoryName"]</td>
                            <td ng-show="!SubCategory">@row["SubCategoryName"]</td>
                            <td ng-show="!Item">@row["ItemName"]</td>
                            <td ng-show="!SubItem">@row["SubItemName"]</td>
                            <td>@row["Question_Type"]</td>
                            <td>@row["QuestionName"]</td>
                            @{ if (row["IsActive"].ToString().Equals("true", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    <td>Yes</td>}
                                else if (row["IsActive"].ToString().Equals("false", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                                {
                                    <td>No</td>}
                                else
                                {
                                    <td></td>
                                }
                            }
                            <td>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Delete", "QuestionMaster", new { @Question_id = row["Question_Id"] })" onclick="return confirm('are you sure you want to delete ?')" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Delete Question"><i class="fa fa-trash fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#d9534f"></i></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "QuestionMaster", new { @Question_id = row["Question_Id"] })" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edit Question"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5cb85c"></i></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
                                <a href="@Url.Action("Details", "QuestionMaster", new { @Question_id = row["Question_Id"] })" style="pointer-events:all" data-toggle="tooltip" title="See Complete Detail of this Question"><i class="fa fa-info fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" style="color:#5bc0de"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        counter = counter + 1;
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

On checkbox I am setting

```
ng-model="ModelValue"
```

And On table Columns

```
ng-show="!ModelValue"
```

and I am also using [Jquery DataTable Plugin](https://datatables.net/)

```
$('[id^="tbl"]').dataTable({
        "order": [[6, "asc"]]
    });
```

When I click on checkbox it does do show hide on columns , but only for first page , when I switch page using pager it does not work for rest of the pages

I have checked the source code of page and ng-show is there on selected columns in every row but does not work other pages .

I am using angular 1x

Comment: Where are your app and your controller? Make your example minimal: 1 checkbox, 1 table. Maybe you'll find your bug in the process of simplifying.

Comment: @RaphaMex , I tried your suggestion , it did not work , But if I apply same logic to hide row on certain conditions than it works for other pages too , but not on columns

Comment: What is this `@{}` syntax?? Please add corresponding tag to your question. Not sure angularjs likes it.

Comment: @RaphaMex , its Asp.Net Core , I have added that Tag too